# Select terms for a taxonomy menu

Tags: routes, taxonomy-terms

What I am looking to achieve is a menu that will list a select number of terms from a vocabulary as a menu.  These select number of terms must be human picked, not just most recent. If this menu is compatible with a responsive menu module, all the better.

I have tried creating a view of these terms (filtered by a bolean field) and using Menu Views module but these modules are not compatible as there is too much markup in a view output. This excessive markup interrupts menu functionality.  I could reduce the amount of HTML markup outputted, but this seams a bit excessive for something which should be simple.

How is the best way to achieve the desired results?

Comment: What is style for views?